# BLE disable pairing outside of an app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've used a device in the past that connects to my smartphone via BLE. It deals with secure data so pairing with a pin was requested. The special feature I am interested in is that the pairing was only possible from the manufacturers app. Outside of it, via my Phones( Android OS) Bluetooth explorer it is not possible to pair with the device.
With the BLE explorer, i can discover the Device Advertisement and it shows me the pairing key.  If I enter the  correct key, the device says pairing failed and aborts the connection. My phohne adds the device to the paird list but communication doesn't work.
I also tested it with the ble scanner app but I'm not able to discover the services and characteristics.
So I guess there might be some extra Data sent from the manufacturers App to the Device while pairing.
Am I right with my suggestion? In which part of my Android app do I have to this feature? I have made an BLE app before where I have to send some symbols to the server that it start sending data, but this is just a simple characteristic write operation and pairing worked without problems also outside the app.
Thank you

Comment: Did you read the hci snoop log generated by the phone when you paired with the other device? There you should see every information exchanged.

Comment: Hi emil,
no I haven't. But that's a good idea. I am looking more about a general explanation. In my previous projects, I've catched the advertisement of the server und implemented the Callback with a "statemachine" consisting of discover services, onServicesDiscovered etc. But it isn't possible to discover services. The connection gets destroyed during the attempt. So I guess there must be a possibility to send a specific command before the discovery process.But I don't know how to do it outside the callback.

Comment: As far as I know you can't really do anything before onServiceDiscovered. Except maybe that the GATT client / server roles are reversed, i.e. the phone is server. But look at the hci log. Otherwise we can just speculate.

Comment: Hi Emil,
I've read the HCi but can't find the clue. I guess because of the encryption that is done to the data I can see the UUIDs but not the value. So I assume that it is not possible to "Hack" the difference that is done within the app. I was hoping to detect my entered key anywhere in the log but after research I came to the point that the key itself is never sent between server and client. It is only used to create the key for future encryption. Is that correct?

Comment: It's the BLE link that's encrypted, not the HCI link. So everything you see is unencrypted. So you should be able to find your answer there.